# Facebook and Twitter APIs performance

Tags: php, performance, facebook-graph-api, twitter

I use `http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=example.com` and `https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://example.com` to pull like and tweet counts from several URLs.

But because I use those two methods to get data about multiple URLs (up to 40), the page takes up to 24 second to load, which is huge.

Is there any other method to get the same data (i.e. like and tweet counts) faster ?

P.S. : I am using PHP.

This is the code :

```
function likes_count($url) {

  $url = urlencode($url);
  $json_string = file_get_contents('http://graph.facebook.com/' . $url);
  $json = json_decode($json_string, true);
  echo "fetching from facebook</br>";
  return intval($json['shares']);

}

function tweets_count($url) {

  $url = urlencode($url);
  $json_string = file_get_contents('http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=' . $url);
  $json = json_decode($json_string, true);
  echo "fetching from twitter</br>";
  return intval($json['count']);

}
```

Comment: It depends on your code. Post it.

Comment: Posting code : done :)

Comment: I don't think that those two functions are to blame. I actually call them more than 40 times (once for every link I have to monitor). I tried to run the code without those functions and it got a lot faster.

Comment: You could try using ajax to load the content gradually into a page. Or is can you cache the resources before they are loaded ?

Comment: No, Ajax is not a good idea in this particular case, since I need all the social data loaded at once to be able to sort links according to their popularity.

Using cache, in the other hand, is a good one. It won't allow me to have a real time sorting, but a small delay is not as bad as that. Thx :)